# When I hit “command”+“return” Mac OS X speaks. How can I disable this?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I’m trying to use [Light Table](http://lighttable.com) which also uses <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>. I can’t find the setting for this in my preferences anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Apple menu > System Preferences > Dictation & Speech > Text to Speech` turn off the *Speak selected text when the key is pressed* option, or customize the hotkey:

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks!  I was expecting this to be in the Keyboard Shortcuts settings.